# External power supply?

Tags: power, arduino-micro

I have a project where I'm looking to power 120 RGB LEDs in a strip (WS2812B).

Obviously an Arduino Micro cannot supply this amount of current so I'm looking to use an external 5V/4A switching power supply (wall-wart) to power the LED's as well as the Arduino.

My question is, can I just split the power from the wall-wart providing 5v_reg directly to the 5V pin on the Arduino Micro and 5v_reg to the LEDs Vss?

It it necessary to use extra bypass capacitors in this case?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> My question is, can I just split the power from the wall-wart providing 5v_reg directly to the 5V pin on the Arduino Micro and 5v_reg to the LEDs Vss?

Yes. As long as it is a clean regulated 5V supply.

> It it necessary to use extra bypass capacitors in this case?

No.

Comment: Great. Are there specified limits as to what voltage range is acceptable to apply to the 5V pin, assuming the regulated supply is non ideal?

Comment: The datasheet for the ATmega32U4 seems to suggest VCC = 2.7V to 5.5V although I'm not sure on this.

Comment: That is correct. However at lower voltages you run into instability with the clock being too fast. Best stick to 4.5V - 5.5V.

Comment: Great, thank you for the practical answer.